# when set ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false, while code execute half way and exit

Tags: sql, database, race-condition

I have a following sql code, if I set AutoDetectChangesEnabled and ValidateOnSaveEnabled  to false. When there is a race condition in database, is it possible that my string process is processing half way then exit the using.

```
using (DbContext dbContext = new DbContext()) {
     dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
     dbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

     string a = dbContext.sp_getsomething().FirstOrDefault();
     string b = a.substring(2);
     //and other string processing 
}
```